# How to copy paste layers from one QGIS project to another?

Tags: qgis, layers, copy

Using QGIS 2.4, how can I copy one or more layers (with its properties, style, and the path of the source data) on QGIS and paste it in a different .QGS project?

I tried to make this, clicking in a layer and drag and drop in the Layers window of another .qgs project but don't take the properties of the first layer.

Comment: I've recently published the 'Copy layers and groups to clipboard' plugin. You can select layers and/or groups from the Layers Panel and paste them into the same or another QGIS instance. http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CopyLayersAndGroupsToClipboard/, preserving position (inside selected groups), symbology, and encoding, among other settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plugin named `Layers menu from project` that lets you import layers from other project files incuding the styling.

The only pitfall: `Attention : the project must be configured to record absolute paths` which is not the default for QGIS. But you can change it in the project properties.

Answer (score 11):

just right click the layer and select save as...layer definition file and save...
then from another project, click the layer menu and select add from layer definition file... and that's it. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In 3.22 ([see changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog322/index.html#data-management)), you can drag and drop from project to project.