# Auto-style shp layers with pre-defined schema in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, style, fields-attributes, file-formats

I have shapefiles with a pre-determined format, but different data.  Is there a way in QGIS to set the style automatically based on pre-determined fields, before any files are open?

I'm thinking something along the lines of a stylesheet which references the fields, possibly based on the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this post [How to copy paste layers from one QGIS project to another?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130758/how-to-copy-paste-layers-from-one-qgis-project-to-another)

You could try following these steps.

1st

> There is a plugin named Layers menu from project that lets you import layers from other project files including the styling.

2nd

> right click the layer and select save as...layer definition file and save... then from another project, click the layer menu and select add from layer definition file